# Is NVS storage reset during an OTA update? (ESP32)

Tags: esp32

I plan to save some settings in the NVS repository of my ESP32, which will also be implemented OTA update.

The question arose, will the data in the NVS storage be reset when the OTA update is launched?

Comment: no. why would it?